# Error: hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a Table OCCUPIED_SEATS consisting only of two foreign keys, SEATS_ID and SCREENING_ID, both of which make a unique index.

How can I make this in Sequelize?

I tried creating the indexes in OCCUPIED_SEATS and the FKs in the other files.

```
const SEATS = require("./Seats");
const SCREENING = require("./Screening");

const OCCUPIED_SEATS = sequelize.define("OCCUPIED_SEATS", {
    //SEATS_ID
    //SCREENING_ID
  },
  {
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: true,
        fields: [SEAT_ID, SCREENING_ID]
      }
    ],
    underscored: true
  }
);

OCCUPIED_SEATS.belongsTo(SEATS, {foreignKey: 'SEAT_ID'});

OCCUPIED_SEATS.sync();
module.exports = OCCUPIED_SEATS;
```

---

```
const OCCUPIED_SEATS = require("./Occupied_Seats");


const SEATS = sequelize.define("SEATS", {
    //ROOM_ID
    SEATS_ID: {       
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    ROW: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    COLUMN: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
  },
  {
    underscored: true
  }
);

SEATS.hasMany(OCCUPIED_SEATS, {foreignKey: 'SEAT_ID'});

module.exports = SEATS;
```

I am getting is the following error.

Error: SEATS.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model.

Comment: I also tried without the line:
OCCUPIED_SEATS.belongsTo(SEATS, {foreignKey: 'SEAT_ID'});
but I'm still having the same error.

Comment: You asked the same question twice, I have answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56694727/problem-coding-a-weak-entity-in-sequelize