# Problem coding a weak entity in sequelize

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I am creating a cinema application. I have modeled the database on mySql but I am having trouble migrating it to Sequelize. I have followed the documentation but I am getting a lot of different errors.

I have tried using associations and indexes (as it should be). [This is the model I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8F1e.jpg).

OCCUPIED_SEATS is composed of only two foreign keys and both make a unique index.

**OCCUPIED_SEATS**:

```
const SEATS = require("./Seats");
const SCREENING = require("./Screening");

const OCCUPIED_SEATS = sequelize.define("OCCUPIED_SEATS", {
    //SEATS_ID
    //SCREENING_ID
  },
  {
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: true,
        fields: [SEAT_ID, SCREENING_ID]
      }
    ],
    underscored: true
  }
);

module.exports = OCCUPIED_SEATS;
```

**SEATS**:

```
const OCCUPIED_SEATS = require("./Occupied_Seats");

const SEATS = sequelize.define("SEATS", {
    SEATS_ID: {       
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    ROW: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    COLUMN: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
  },
  {
    underscored: true
  }
);

SEATS.hasMany(OCCUPIED_SEATS, {foreignKey: 'SEAT_ID'})

module.exports = SEATS;
```

**SCREENING**:

```
const OCCUPIED_SEATS = require("./Occupied_Seats");

const SCREENING = sequelize.define("SCREENING", {
    SCREENING_ID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    SCREENING_START_TIME: {
        type: Sequelize.TIME,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    DATE: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    }
  },
  {
    underscored: true,
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: true,
        fields: [ROOM_ID, SCREENING_START_TIME, DATE]
      }
    ]
  }
);

SCREENING.hasMany(OCCUPIED_SEATS, {foreignKey: 'SCREENING_ID'});

module.exports = SCREENING;
```

The error I am getting when I try this is:

```
[] Error: SEATS.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

How should I code the model?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in the new version of Sequelize you have to define your models through `Sequelize.Model` type:

```
class Seats extends Sequelize.Model {}
Seats.init({
    id: {       
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    row: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
   ...
});
module.exports = Seats;
```

And then somewhere else:

```
Seats.hasMany(OccupiedSeatc, {foreignKey: 'SEAT_ID'})
```

See [model definition docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html) and [accociation docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html).